search text in comma separated column using Criterial Step R2dbcEntityTemplate postgres
I am trying to search text in column which contains text with comma seperated.
sql query is
select * from tags_report where string_to_array(tag, ';') && array['TAG1', 'TAG2']
same thing i have to do in java with Criteria Steps and R2dbcEntityTemplate
